# How to add a 1D array to a 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays, jtable

Sorry first time asking a question here.

If I have a 2D Array like this:

```
int[][] array2d = {{1, 2, 3}, {6, 7, 8}};
```

How do I add multiple 1D Arrays like this:

```
int[] array1d = {3, 2, 1};
int[] array1d2 = {8, 7, 6};
```

so that my original 2d array becomes this:

```
int[][] array2d = {{1, 2, 3}, {6, 7, 8}, {3, 2, 1}, {8, 7, 6}};
```

**Note:** this is for adding information from a JTextfield into a JTable whenever a button is pressed. So, the 2d array will be used as the data inside the table. If there is a better way to accomplish this I would appreciate it too. =)

Comment: You should allocate enough rows in your 2D arrays. The way you initialize your 2D array, it cannot have more than 2 rows.

Comment: Oh, I was trying to avoid that. I guess there is another way to add data into a table. I will look for it. Thanks

Comment: If you're trying to avoid worrying about array length, you might consider using an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), (or some other Collection implementation), instead.

Comment: I was thinking maybe a LinkedList would that work for JTables? Sorry I'm just learning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your array :

```
int[][] array2d = {{1, 2, 3}, {6, 7, 8}};
```

is fixed in size, so you would have to create a copy with enough capacity to hold the new values:

```
int[][] newArray = Arrays.copyOf(array2d, 4);
newArray[2] = array1d;
newArray[3] = array1d2;
```

To add your data to the `JTable` the arrays would have to be first converted to a non-primitive type such as an `Integer` array. One option is to use the Apache Commons:

```
model.addRow(ArrayUtils.toObject(array));
```

for each row of the array.

Comment: Well, what I'm trying to do is have a panel in which a user enters data. When a button is pressed, the data gets added to the table.

Comment: You just need to split out your `Strings` into a format where you can build an object array so that you can use for your `addRow` call. Have a look at an [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing.table/DefaultTableModeladdRowObjectrowData.htm). This may require a new post.

Answer (score 1):

arrays are fixed size so to append it you need to resize the array look at java.util.Arrays.

then set the arrays location

```
arra2d[index] = array1d;
```

is there are reason you are not using

```
TableModel.addRow(dataArray);
```

?

Comment: I'm just learning how to use JTables. From what I've learned I think I'm supposed to initialize JTables with a 1d array for columns and a 2d array for the data. I have no idea what TableModel.addRow(dataArray); does but I will look into it!